# Probability that the product of three consecutive natural numbers is a multiple of $9$ is?

Tags: probability, contest-math

> Three consecutive natural numbers are selected at random out of the
> first $101$ natural numbers. What is the probability that the product
> of these three numbers is a multiple of $9$?

Pairs of $3$ consecutive natural numbers that can be formed out of the first $101$ natural numbers $=99$

$(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5), (4,5,6), (5,6,7), (6,7,8), (7,8,9), (8,9,10), (9,10,11), (10,11,12)$ $\Rightarrow 10$ pairs 
$(11,12,13), (12,13,14), (13,14,15), (14,15,16), (15,16,17), (16,17,18), (17,18,19), (18,19,20), (19,20,21), (20,21,22)$ $\Rightarrow 10$ pairs 
........
........
........
$(91,92,93), (92,93,94), (93,94,95), (94,95,96), (95,96,97), (96,97,98), (97,98,99), (98,99,100), (99,100,101) \Rightarrow 9$ pairs

Now every set of $10$ pairs or $9$ pairs will have $3$ pairs whose product will be the multiple of $9$. So total pairs which are multiple of $9 = 30$

Probability $=\frac{30}{99} = \frac{10}{33}$

But this is not the correct answer that has been given. What am I doing wrong? Please help !!!

Comment: Hint: for a product to be divisible by 9, one of the numbers in the triplet must also be divisible by 9. There are three triplets for every number divisible by 9. There are 11 numbers divisible by 9. So the total is 3 x 11 = 33. You probably missed counting 90 and 99 separately when you said every 10 triplets have 3 such triplets.

Comment: What is 'a pair' in your question?

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent question: given $n \in \mathbb{N} \cap [1, 99]$ selected uniformly at random, what is the probability that $n(n+1)(n+2)$ is divisible by 9?

Exactly one of $n$, $(n+1)$, or $(n+2)$ will be divisible by 3. So the only way that their product will be divisible by 9, is if $n$, $(n+1)$, or $(n+2)$ is divisible by 9.

If we now consider the first 9 natural numbers $n\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, this is true for $n\in\{7,8,9\}$, i.e. 3 out of every 9, or $p=1/3$. The pattern will simply repeat for 11 groups of 9 numbers, and in fact the last group ends nicely with 99, so this is also the final probability.

To connect it back to your original answer: every set of 9 triples will have 3 triples which are divisible by 9, and there are 11 such sets, so $p = (3\cdot 11)/(9\cdot 11) = 33/99 = 1/3$.